# Memory allocation growth on a method which fetches server data

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I have a method which fetches data from server. I'm calling the method several times inside a loop. The problem is when i use instrument to check memory allocation, i have increase in live memory in each of the method call. BTW I am using ARC.
[image: Memory Allocation]

```
-(NSArray*)callService
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: serviceURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL; 
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *array = [(NSArray*) [responseString JSONValue] autorelease];
    responseString=nil;
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, you should call release for the `request`, `Countjson` and `responseString` before return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with SBJSON parser. Since i'm using iOS 5, i used NSJSONSerialization and it works like a charm.

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

instead of the JSONValue

Answer (score 0):

> I have a method which fetches data from server. I'm calling the method
>   several times inside a loop.

**Don't**. Call one, wait for the response and call the next one.

**Edit 1:**

> A synchronous load is built on top of the asynchronous
>   loading code made available by the class. The calling thread is
>   blocked while the asynchronous loading system performs the URL load on
>   a thread spawned specifically for this load request. No special
>   threading or run loop configuration is necessary in the calling thread
>   in order to perform a synchronous load.
>
> Because this call can potentially take several minutes to
>   fail (particularly when using a cellular network in iOS), you should
>   never call this function from the main thread of a GUI application.

Comment: it's a synchronous request. So it will automatically wait for response.

Comment: Yea. But i'm having problem with memory.

Comment: Could you try what I suggested? One after the previous has been sent.

Comment: I don't know what you meant. could u be little more precise.

Comment: Do you mean calling the method in seperate thread would solve memory problem?

Comment: What I mean is create some logical and don't use a `for`cycle do a request one at a time and do it in an Async way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13472/discussion-between-pritesh-acharya-and-jacky-boy)

Answer (score 0):

If you have zombies on (scheme settings) ensure you turn them off while testing in Instruments for memory usage. The default setting for NSDeallocateZombies is NO, so zombies won't be deleted at all. So either set NSZombiesEnabled to NO (or the equivalent scheme checkbox) or leave in on but set NSDeallocateZombies to YES.

Comment: I tried both NSZombiesEnabled and NSDeallocateZombies. both didn't work. It showed the same amount of memory